# Как разместить на экране нужное количество одинаковых div?

Tags: jquery, html, php, css

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как разместить на экране нужное количество одинаковых div

1. Заданное количество.
2. Во весь экран (от 1 до 30, например).

Comment: Ждешь, пока будут выпытывать? Расскажи, как именно они должны располагаться, что ли.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Пример](http://tympanus.net/Development/DynamicGrid/). Разбирайтесь )

Comment: Хороший пример, то что надо. Только как задать нужное количество Get запросом ?

Comment: Посмотрите, что там происходит, когда выбираешь в левом верхнем углу новое кол-во блоков. И подставьте туда GET параметры из `window.location'.

Comment: Если бы моих способностей было бы достаточно для этого, я бы отвечал на вопросы а не задавал их.